# ¿Como seleccionar elementos que son duplicados n veces en una lista?

Tags: python

Implemente una función, repetidos(lista, cantidad) que reciba una lista, y devuelva una lista sin los elementos repetidos cantidad veces. Por ejemplo:

```
repetidos([1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 2, 4, 3, 4], 3)
```

Devolvería **[3, 7]**

hice esto:

```
def repetidos(lista, cantidad):
    lista_final = []
    for i in lista:
        if (i not in lista_final) and (i in cantidad):
            lista_final.append(i)
    return lista_final

def repetidos(lista, cantidad):
    num = lista.count (cantidad)
    return num
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español... Por favor date una vuelta por [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta... de paso podes hacer el [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio... por favor hacelo para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida y no tengas puntuaciones negativas... mucha suerte

Comment: `[i for i in set(lista) if lista.count(i) == cantidad]` esto deberia hacer lo que ocupas, si ocupas explicación me comentas

Answer (score 2):

Puesto que parece un ejercicio, voy a darte una respuesta que se parece a lo que habías intentado hasta ahora, y es que hay formas mejores de hacerlo pero es probable que aún no las conozcas.

**En qué fallan tus funciones**

En la primera función que incluyes creas una lista vacía `lista_final` y haces un bucle que recorre la lista `[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 2, 4, 3, 4]` y analiza si el número está en la `lista_final` (hasta aquí bien) y si el **número está en cantidad**, este es el problema, ya que cantidad es `3` por lo que las condiciones del `if` únicamente se van a cumplir para el numero que hayas puesto en `cantidad` y será el único numero que añada.

La segunda función que has intentado lo que hace es contar el número de veces que está el `número` que has puesto en cantidad en `lista`.

**Cómo solucionarlo**

Podrías aprovechar la primera función que tienes, y si en vez de pasarle tu lista, le pasas una del tipo `[[numero,frecuencia],[numero, frecuencia],...]` en este caso

```
lista = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1], [6, 0], [7, 3]]
```

Solo tendrías que buscar en qué casos la frecuencia es igual al número que has puesto en cantidad. Repito, no es la mejor manera de hacerlo, pero al ser un ejercicio, y aprovechar tu función, creo que te puede ayudar a entender lo que estás haciendo.

Si ejecutas:

```
lista = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1], [6, 0], [7, 3]]

def repetidos(lista, cantidad):
    lista_final = []
    for i in lista:
        if (i[0] not in lista_final) and (i[1] == cantidad):
            lista_final.append(i[0])
    return lista_final

print(repetidos(lista, 3))
```

**Obtener la lista con frecuencias**

Esta parte te la voy a dejar que la hagas, puesto que se puede hacer con partes del código que ya habías hecho, pero te digo unos pasos a seguir:

Puedes crear una función que recorra desde el `0` hasta el **máximo** número de tu `lista` y que para cada número añada en una `lista_nueva` el `[número, cantidad de veces que aparece número en lista]`

Answer (score 1):

Antes de nada, creo que lo has planteado de forma incorrecta, o te has liado al explicarlo, dado que si lo que tiene que devolver es la lista sin los elementos repetidos cantidad de veces, no te devolvería 3 y 7, te devolvería 1,2,5,8,2,4,4.

Te pongo los dos ejemplos, para obtener únicamente los elementos duplicados X veces, es bastante simple:

```
listaoriginal=[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 2, 4, 3, 4]
def repetidos(lista, cantidad):
    listanoreps = list(dict.fromkeys(listaoriginal))
    for i in listanoreps:
        if listaoriginal.count(i)==cantidad:
            numreps.append(i)
    print(numreps)
```

**Devoleria: [3, 7]**

Lo que hace es básicamente, obtener una lista sin ningún repetido para posteriormente contar cada uno de estos números en la lista original y lo añade a una nueva lista en la que solo estarán dichos repetidos.

En el segundo caso, también es bastante sencillo, hacemos un bucle en el vamos a contar cuantos números hay de cada, y si coincide con la cantidad establecida, simplemente entra en un bucle extra, que gira tantas veces como la cantidad, eliminando en cada giro una copia del numero repetido:

```
listaoriginal=[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 2, 4, 3, 4]
def repetidos(lista, cantidad):
    for num in listaoriginal:
        if lista.count(num)==cantidad:
           for i in range(cantidad):
                listaoriginal.remove(num)
    print(listaoriginal)
```

**Devolvería: [1, 2, 5, 8, 2, 4, 4]**

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda, si necesitas alguna explicación será un placer ayudar

*Edito para añadir el código completa y evitar confusiones*

Comment: En ambas funciones utilizas variables que no han sido declaradas, por lo que en ambos casos van a dar un error

Comment: Únicamente era un ejemplo de como podría hacerlo, obviamente luego el tiene que adaptarlo a su propio código cambiando mis variables por las suyas, mas que darle el código trataba de explicarle como funcionaba